# Adding alfresco 4.2 as a repositiory in liferay 6.1 using CMIS(AtomPub)

Tags: liferay, alfresco, liferay-6, cmis, opencmis

I downloaded liferay 6.1 with bundled tomcat from the website and i am currently trying to add a new repository in the documents and media portlet, using the process described in [here](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository).

Although the integration succeeds, in the repository list, the newly created cmis repository (alfresco) displays the following warning: "an unexpected error occured while connecting to the repository". Nothing on the catalina.out and the liferay logs though. Then when i try to create a subfolder, i get the following exception: in apache chemistry CmisRuntimeException: Length Required.

I checked with wireshark and, in fact the POST request from liferay to alfresco misses the content-length indeed. How can i enable it ? has anyone had similar issues ?

Any help will be much appreciated.

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

1. Portal Settings - Authentication - *Use screen name.
   Nickname and password for account creating repository should be same as for alfresco.*
2. Add parameters to portal-ext.properties
   **session.store.password=true** and **company.security.auth.type=screenName**
3. Create repository. Use URL path **/alfresco/service/cmis** (not /alfresco/cmisatom). Live repository ID blank.

Read more at
[Mounting Multiple CMIS Repositories on Liferay 6.1](http://www.liferay.com/de/web/alexander.chow/blog/-/blogs/7670631) and [CMIS Repository](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/CMIS+Repository#section-CMIS+%C2%ADRepository-FAQ).

Comment: Also, user credentials could be defined at portal-ext.properties
`dl.store.impl=com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.CMISStore`
`dl.store.cmis.credentials.username=username`
`dl.store.cmis.credentials.password=password`
`dl.store.cmis.repository.url=http://<host>:8080/alfresco/cmisatom`